# Changing prices in OpenCart according to script

Tags: php, opencart

I'm setting up a retail business to sell gold over the internet, using opencart. The difference is that I will only accept bitcoins (BTC), a new cryptographic currency.

The problem is that precious metal prices and the BTC/GBP exchange are very volatile. Thus I need my opencart prices to automatically update at a fairly frequent rate to avoid being caught out via moving exchange rates and selling at a loss.

I've written a script that is attached that pulls the gold, silver, and platinum price, then denominates the prices in bitcoins.

So, for each metallic item on the website, I'd like the prices of all products within the catalogue to change automatically (every 15 minutes would be ideal).

**My question is: How do I update prices in the opencart database, according to a script?**

The price has to change based on four things:
the type of precious metal the item contains.
the percentage markup for that item
the weight of precious metal the item contains.
the type of coin the item is.

I'd like these things to be attributes editable within opencart. For every item, there would be four (extra) attributes

Metal type
     => Gold
     => Silver
     => Platinum
     => Not a metal (for other items, it would then ignore all weight, price changes)
Percentage Markup
        Percentage (integer?)
Weight
        Integer
Coin Markup
        Integer
"
So, let's say I'm selling a quarter ounce gold coin, of the Krugerrand type:

a quarter ounce gold coin weighs 7.77 grams, so on the product page the weight would be listed with that figure. The base price would be set at 7.77 grams * Gold price in grams (this figure is fetched using the attached php script).

My default markup from the wholesale gold price would be 10%, the 'base' price would be increased by 10%, this would also be listed on the product page.

Krugerrands, for historical reasons tend to include a value over and above the gold wholesale price. so the coin mark up would be around 5 bitcoins, the price would be increased to reflect this.
"
None of these price fiddles should be seen by the buyer, they should just see the price changes to reflect all of these

Every hour the price of all the products would change, to reflect the changes in the gold price, and the BTC GBP exchange rates.

Below is a PHP script to pull a gold price, a silver price, and a platinum price, then denominate the price of a gram of metal in bitcoins. It's the first thing I've ever programmed, so might be a little verbose, or not follow given conventions. The answer is likely to be very complicated, so I don't expect a full one. It'd be nice to receive some pointers though!

```
 <?php
  /* This is a script that ultimately displays the price of gold in grams, denominated       in Bitcoins (BTC), a non fiat cryptographic currency. This is also the first thing I have ever programmed, so be nice */

 // line break variable
 $br = "<br> <br>";


    // CURL begin
//curl session 1: grab metal prices
$ch1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch1, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://drayah.no.de/metals/latest' );
curl_setopt( $ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
$metalsdata = curl_exec( $ch1 );


// curl session 2: Grab exchange rate for BTC/GBP
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://mtgox.com/api/1/BTCGBP/public/ticker' );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 1000);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'useragent');
$btcgbpdata = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );

// curl session 3: Grab  British pounds to USD exchange rates
$ch1 = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch1, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://raw.github.com/currencybot/open-exchange-rates/master/latest.json' );
curl_setopt( $ch1, CURLOPT_Rcheck if my code isETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
$currencydata = curl_exec( $ch1 );


//gold digest: turn JSON data into readable php, and extract the gold price
$metals  = json_decode( $metalsdata, true, 512 );
$goldprice = $metals['gold']['quote'];
$silverprice = $metals['silver']['quote'];
$platprice = $metals['platinum']['quote'];

//BTC digest of JSON

$btcgbp = json_decode( $btcgbpdata, true, 512 );
$btcgbpvwap = ($btcgbp['return']['vwap']['value']);
echo "$btcgbpvwap pounds per BTC";
echo $br;


//currency digest of JSON
$currency = json_decode( $currencydata, true, 512 );
$usdgbp = ($currency['rates']['GBP']);
echo "$usdgbp pence per USD dollar";
echo $br;
echo $br;
// convert metals into price per ounce in pounds

$goldpounds = $goldprice * $usdgbp;
$silverpounds = $silverprice * $usdgbp;
$platpounds = $platprice * $usdgbp;
echo "GBP $goldpounds per ounce of gold";
echo $br;
echo "GBP $silverpounds per ounce of silver";
echo $br;   
echo "GBP $platpounds per ounce of platinum";
echo $br;
echo $br;

//metals prices in grams
$goldpoundsgram = $goldpounds / 31.1034768;
$silverpoundsgram = $silverpounds / 31.1034768;
$platpoundsgram = $platpounds / 31.1034768;
echo "$goldpoundsgram pounds per gram of gold";
echo $br;
echo "$silverpoundsgram pounds per gram of silver";
echo $br;
echo "$platpoundsgram pounds per gram of platinum";
echo $br;
echo $br;
// metal prices denominated in BTC
$btcgoldgram = ($goldpoundsgram / $btcgbpvwap);
$btcsilvergram = ($silverpoundsgram / $btcgbpvwap);
$btcplatgram = ($platpoundsgram / $btcgbpvwap);
echo "<b>"; 
echo $btcgoldgram;
echo " bitcoins per gram of gold";
echo $br;   
echo $btcsilvergram;
echo " bitcoins per gram of silver";
echo $br;
echo $btcplatgram;
echo " bitcoins per gram of platinum";

?>
```

Comment: If you're after how this should be done and a step by step guide, I'm afraid you're in the wrong place. You've not actually even specified a question, only told us your goals. If you need to add fields, and use them in opencart, you're going to have to hire a professional to do this for you or learn OpenCart's MVC structure and work with it

Comment: Dear Jay, could you tell me where I could learn about the MVC structure of opencart. The documentation is hopeless.

Comment: The easiest way is to use a simple controller file to begin with, and work from there. As you say the documentation is lacking, so the only way to learn is to take it apart and learn from small edits til you're comfortable with it

Comment: @JayGilford I know this post is quite old, but this is an interesting topic. Could OP have created a custom currency which reflected the mapped-bitcoin prices to his "new" currency (which changes depending on the price of bitcoin and gold)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually `price` is just a numeric field in table `product`, you can update it with a simple update statement based on `product_id`.

There is also a column `cost` in the same table, used just to report income in administration panel. You could update that as well, if you are interested in such report.

To recover the `product_id` you can use product' name from `product_description` (beware names are *localized*). Say your DB contains products named *gram of silver* then your update could be

```
update product p,product_description d set price=$btcsilvergram
 where p.product_id=d.product_id and name='gram of silver'
```

Values are tax free.

Comment: feel free to upvote or accept, we all strive for a bit of reputation!

Comment: And to adjust that according to weight and so forth I would be able to

set price= ($btcsilvergram * $productweight) + $cointype

Comment: Accepted, this definitely comes under pointers for further research, I don't have enough rep to upvote!

Answer (score 0):

I am looking at something similar. Since my supplier prices are all in USD (i.e. none of them will accept bitcoin yet), I would prefer to hard code those prices into Opencart and then use Opencart's built-in exchange rate converter to charge enough bitcoin to cover my costs on any given day. By tweaking my admin and theme settings, I can display prices only in BTC and take away the ability for visitors to change the default currency (menu items, modules, etc). Then, I only need to update the USD->BTC rate in Opencart periodically and all product prices will update appropriately - daily, 4x daily, hourly, etc.

The Opencart database has a table named "currency" that stores the appropriate exchange rates.

Bitcoin is usually quoted in BTC-USD ($XXusd per 1btc), but I need the USD-BTC rate since my prices are stored in USD. I inverted a sample bitcoin price (1 / $4 => .25btc per $1) and stored that in Opencart.

```
CURRENCY:
(4, 'Bitcoin', 'btc', 'B⃦', 'BTC', '2', 0.25000000, 1, '2012-04-10 12:13:45'),  
(2, 'US Dollar', 'USD', '$', '', '2', 1.00000000, 1, '2012-04-10 12:12:33');
```

Now, I just a script to update the ".25000000" value whenever needed. I am planning to sidestep the whole Opencart system and setup a cron job on the server to update the value once a day. I have a couple alerts setup elsewhere to notify me if there is a big crash in bitcoin prices. If some extreme price change happens, I can log into Opencart and manually adjust the rate.

Hope this helps :-)